# Retrieve all information of a specific tv show episode including actors and director using aggregate function mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to retrieve all information of a specific tv show episode including actors and director.

This is my tv show model.js:

```js
const tvShowSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    year: Number,
    country: String,
    seasons: [{
        number: Number,
        year: Number,
        episodes: [{
                title: String,
                number: Number,
                releasedOn: Date,
                description: String,
                cast: [{
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'actors'
                }],
                director: {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'directors'
                }
            },
            {
                timeStamps: true,
                versionKey: false
            }
        ]
    }]
});
```

this is the tv show Routes.js:

```js
router.get("/showid/tvepisodeid/:tvshowid/seasonid/:seasonId/episodeid/:episodeId",
    tvShowsCtrl.getTvShowEpisode);
```

And this is the tv show controller.js:

```js
import TVShow from "../models/TVShow";


import {
    Types
} from "mongoose";


export const getTvShowEpisode = async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const id = req.params.id;

        const seasonId = req.params.seasonId;

        const episodeId = req.params.episodeId;

        const tvShowEpisode = await TVShow.aggregate([

            {
                $match: {

                    "_id": Types.ObjectId(id),
                    "seasons._id": Types.ObjectId(seasonId),
                    "episodes._id": Types.ObjectId(episodeId)

                }
            }, {
                $addFields: {
                    "isEpisode": {
                        $eq: ['$seasons.episodes', selectedEpisode]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $addFields: {
                    "cast.isEpisode": {
                        $eq: ['$seasons.episodes', selectedEpisode]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'actors',
                    localField: 'seasons.episodes.cast',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'actors'
                }
            },

            {
                $addFields: {
                    "director.isEpisode": {
                        $eq: ['$seasons.episodes', selectedEpisode]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'directors',
                    localField: 'seasons.episodes.director',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'director'
                }
            },

            /* {$unwind: '$seasons'},  */

            {
                $match: {
                    "seasons._id": Types.ObjectId(seasonId)
                }
            }, {
                $project: {
                    "_id": Types.ObjectId(id)
                },
                "episode": '$seasons.episodes'
            }


        ]);

        if (tvShowEpisode) {
            res.send(tvShowEpisode);
        } else {
            res
                .status(404)
                .send({
                    mensaje: `tv show episode not found`
                });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: `error: \n\n${error}`
        });
    }

};
```

the expected output should be like this:

```json
{
   "seasons":[
      "number":1,
      "year":2019,
      "episodes":[
         "title":"the restaurant",
         "number":2,
         "releasedOn":"2019-05-10T14:00:00.025Z",
         "description":"the restaurant is new",
         "cast":[
            {
               "_id":"84834h4hrtbb54y4hu4u5h9",
               "fullName":"Keith Price",
               "age":25,
               "nationality":"american"
            },
            {
               "_id":"82j4hy43u45hu54huuh539",
               "fullName":"Cindy Kat",
               "age":28,
               "nationality":"welsh"
            }
         ],
         "director":{
            "_id":"urirnjr43u242344343",
            "fullName":"maurice klossman",
            "nationality":"polish"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

How can I fixed these issues?, why the code is not working?, I want when I'm typing url passing respective parameters got the expected output but in postman I've got the message '500 Internal Server Error'.

I've got some issues. I've tried many ways using aggregate function to show only a specific show tv including actors and director but I don't know how to do to code works.

I'd like to know what is wrong with my tv show controller method.

The log error: "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators"

Comment: What is the content of `console.log(error);` just before `res.status(500).send(...)`.

Comment: I've fixed the first issue. I've added let selectedEpisode = null before aggregate and [] parameters of aggregate and this is the issue: "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators"

Comment: The actual error is: "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators", how can I fix?, please, could you show me the issues?